# Facebook Registration Plugin prefills fields without permission?

Tags: authentication, facebook

My understanding was that the registration plugin allows you to use the same reg form for users not registering with Facebook as well with Facebook. However, if a user is logged into Facebook and visits the registration page the form prefills information and only gives them the option to register with Facebook.  That's kind of a freaky user experience.  They hit the register button on your website and it auto fills fields with Facebook info without permission.  Just because a user is logged into facebook doesn't necessarily mean they actually want to create the account with their Facebook information.

Here's what I have handled so far by the registration plugin:

1. User is not logged into Facebook and registers via the plugin, but with my site authentication not Facebook.
2. User is not logged into Facebook, uses the plugin to log into Facebook, fields are prefilled and user registers via Facebook.

**Here's what I dont have handled

3. User is already logged into Facebook, but may want to register with my site authentication and NOT connect the account to their Facebook account.  Currently, it prefills the forms and provides them with only a register button connecting Facebook to my app.**

Basically, I want the user to have to opt-in to register with Facebook even if they are logged into Facebook, but I want to use the Registration plugin form.  Is this possible?

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: "Currently, it prefills the forms" --- what "it"? Pre-filled with fb data forms violate facebook TOS.

Comment: @zerkms, not exactly..[reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/user_registration)

Comment: @ifaour: oh, it is built by fb team... Then sorry. Just thought it is someone custom plugin which definitely would violate TOS then ;-) Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is something ***similar*** to [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/) approach, where you can by default wrap and hide the "Login with facebook" button (or the registration form if the user is already logged in and connected!) and for example in your form div/container have a checkbox (a location over the flow is preferred) stating:

> Register with my Facebook account

Or something more *catchy* and when the user clicks/checks the input the facebook DIV will slide down and used instead of your registration routine.

Comment: Yah I could do, but what's the point of using the registration plugin if I have to have a seperate form?  On the dev page they say 
"The plugin also allows users who do not have a Facebook account, or do not wish to sign up for your site using Facebook to use the same form as those who are connecting with Facebook. This eliminates the need to provide two separate login experiences."

Comment: There's no point since you need the same form and have it pre-filled on certain cases only...unless if you managed to have a link/checkbox outside the FB registration form that would re-invoke the plugin with the `fields` options have the `view` sit to `not_prefilled`

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that even though the Facebook form prefills the form without the users permission there is an x next to their name that allows them to clear the form and sign in with our reg system using the FB form.  I'm gonna go that route. Thakns!

Answer (score 1):

A user can clear the fields by ckicking the X when mouseover the name field